# What are the default values of the Synaptic Finger property?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

My first time post here. I have been using Ubuntu 16 on HP Elitebook 2560P for a few years now and recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18. Immediately after upgrading I noticed the touchpad was a lot less responsive than before. I started investigating the issue and fooled around with some of the Synaptics settings. I feel the Synaptics driver has way too many options, and I possibly messed up a few things.

I would like to know what the default values of the Synaptics Finger properties are, as these aren't mentioned in the man pages, so I can compare the current settings with the default ones.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: So this is a Ubuntu Core 16 system you upgrade to Ubuntu Core 18?  As the 16 product is intended for *headless* server operation, touchpad usually isn't a concern?   Were you by chance using a 16.04 syste,? that was upgrade to 18.04?  as 16 != 16.04, 18 != 18.04 with the different format (*year* versus *year.month*) highlighting different Ubuntu products.

Comment: well, the only thing I learned so far is that I joined a forum of nit-picking geeks; first of all someone found it absolutely necessary to edit my post for typos and such, then someone else made it a point to be anal about version numbers when this is not relevant to the question. Exactly the reason why Linux distros never will come anything close in popularity to e.g.Windows and MacOS.

I'm out of here. Ciao!

Comment: Version numbers ARE relevant. E.g. 18.10 is off-topic, but 18.04 isn't.